# Multiple Column OrderBy using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm having a collection, the schema and values are depicted in the following Table

Schema: `List<Person>`

```
class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasMedicalInsurance { get; set; }
    public bool HasLifeInsurance { get; set; }
    public bool HasBikeInsurance { get; set; }
}


PersonID    Name        HasMedicalInsurance    HasLifeInsurance    HasBikeInsurance
____________________________________________________________________________________
1           Ram         FALSE                  TRUE                FALSE
2           Sita        TRUE                   FALSE               FALSE
3           Lakshman    FALSE                  FALSE               TRUE
4           Hanuman     FALSE                  TRUE                FALSE
5           Ravanan     TRUE                   FALSE               FALSE
6           Bharadan    TRUE                   FALSE               FALSE
```

I need to sort based on the following criteria

1. HasMedicalInsurance
2. HasLifeInsurance
3. HasBikeInsurance

Who are all having Medical Insurance they should come first then Life Insurance and by Bike Insurance.

**Note:** The said collection has the Person's record, each person should
have only one Insurance, that may be Medical / Life / Bike.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], we won't do the entire code for you. Also add the technology to which LinQ is pointing to (LinQ to objects, EF, LinQ to SQL?)

Comment: And maybe add what's stopping you and how the `GroupBy` in the question title fits the actual question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer If the title is wrong kindly suggest the appropriate title.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan The only one who knows if the title or the question is wrong - is you! Did you just add those terms off-the-cuff or did they have any relevance to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you don't want to group at all, but instead you want to sort by multiple criteria.

```
List<Person> people; // initialize your data

var sorted = people.OrderByDescending(x => x.HasMedicalInsurance)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.HasLifeInsurance)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.HasBikeInsurance)
    .ToList();
```

Note: by using the `...Descending` variants, the `true` values are sorted before the `false` values.

Comment: Assuming that *"each person should have only one Insurance"* is true, the last `ThenByDescending` could be omitted. (If everyone has **exactly** one)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer true. However I'd rather sort it as long as I'm not 100% sure that every person has an insurance.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - Kindly see the Note section in the Question.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan That's where I quoted from.